# How to check for program exit code in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I want to check in a shell script whether subversion is installed.
For that I chose to check the exit code after the program has been executed.
I tried using `command svn`, but that prints out the output of the command (Type 'svn help' for usage.).
If I suppress it with `2>/dev/null` the result is an empty string.

How could I make it work?

Comment: @akira - should I care? If I don't get a satisfying answer, I don't approve any. If that's what that is about...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exit code of the last executed program is stored in `$?`.

Comment: ... "so do a `echo $?` and have a look".

Comment: @shellholic - thx, helped.  @akira - stop post-hunting...

Comment: @jurchiks: stopping what?

Comment: @shellholic - do you, by any chance, know, how to do the same in Windows? I'm writing the same script for both Windows and Linux.

Comment: @jurchiks answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line

Comment: @shellholic - already found it, but thanks :) I've even used it before, just forgot.  Now just gotta find out how to check if variable is digit.